# Read public MSMQ remotely from Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp, msmq

I'm trying to read a public MSMQ from a remote (Server 2008) machine.

I know XP has MSMQ 3.0, and I've found some information that it doesn't support transactional, non-local receiving.  Does that include trying to read from a remote queue?

I've tried all sorts of combinations, and the only way I can read a message from the queue is by using:

```
Msg = mDSQueue.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

I need to be able to do this in a transaction.  Any tips?  It seems information for public MSMQ's, and using them remotely, are hard to come by.

//in before reading remotely has poor performance.

Comment: Document whether these machines login to the same domain controller and whether the queue is registered with AD.

Comment: Yes, same domain, and yes the queues are on active directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know XP has MSMQ 3.0, and I've found
>   some information that it doesn't
>   support transactional, non-local
>   receiving. Does that include trying to
>   read from a remote queue?

Yes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/12/11/how-do-i-get-transactional-remote-receives.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/21/remote-transactional-reads-only-work-in-msmq-4-0.aspx

Cheers

John Breakwell

Comment: Thanks... was hoping I would be able to debug locally.  Still can't get it working between two Server 2008 machines though.

Comment: What error code do you get when trying with two Windows Server 2008 machines?